# Set x axis locator at hour intervals on matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to create a figure with four subplots using the Matplotlib object based approach. I am having trouble setting the x-axis to hourly markers on each plot. With my present code the hourly marks are retained only on the last of the four subplots

I have a list which contains four dataframes that were read in from CSV. I used pd.to_datetime to create an index. No problem. 
I can loop through the four dataframes and plot my y variable (TS_comp) against time. this works fine and I get date/time on each x-axis. But what I want is to have just hour markers on each of the x axis. When I add code in the loop to set the major locator it ends up that the x-axis labels are wiped on the first three subplots. The two lines of code from the loop below are:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H'))
```

I do not understand why this is happening as each time it goes through the loop it should be addressing a different axis object. Note x-axis time ranges are different so not a simple matter of sharing the x-axis across the subplots.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
i=0
hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1)
for ax in fig.get_axes():
   ax.plot(dfs[i].TS_comp,'k-',markersize = 0.5)   
   ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
   ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H'))
   i=i+1;
```

Expect to get hourly markers on each of the subplots, ended up with hourly markers on just the last plot

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368302/matplotlib-hourlocator-steals-my-x-labels

Comment: It's risky to use the same locator on different axes. Create a new `hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1)` locator **inside** the loop, one for each axes.

Comment: Thank you IOBErnest (and Diziet Asahi for editing my first stack posting to show the plot). This fixed the problem. Very much appreciated.